# Вылетает приложение при начале зарядки смартфона и при отключении ее

Tags: android

Приложение загружено на смартфон. Заметил, что когда включаю телефон на зарядку при открытом приложении, оно "к сожалению, прекращает свою работу". То же самое, когда снимаю зарядку. Во всех других случаях работает стабильно.

Comment: Без логов ошибки помочь вам практически нереально.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб А как получить эти логи на самом смартфоне? ОС - Андроид 6.0.

Comment: Ну... Включите AndroidStudio, переключите телефон в дебаг режим и смотрите в ЛогКат...

Comment: Вы имеете в виду подключить телефон через USB или WiFi в качестве отладчика через AVD к AndroidStudio? Есть ли способ посмотреть на ошибки без связи с AndroidStudio? В шестой версии анонсировались средства для разработчиков...

Comment: Ну, вроде для любой версии в маркете лежат проги для просмотра логов, но, думаю, замучаетесь там искать... В самих логах всмысле нужную инфу. ИМХО, проще через студию.

Comment: Поддерживаю, добавьте логи из студии - просто и быстро.

Comment: Ну а так, единственная догадка, что в приложении есть методы, которые отслеживают состоянии зарядки устройства, а в манифесте не прописаны нужные permissions.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, @Vyacheslav Martynenko. Вот Вы пишете, "просто и быстро", "Включите AndroidStudio, переключите телефон в дебаг режим". Можете ли Вы прямо написать что делать по шагам? AndroidStudio включил, юсб подключил, отладку по юсб для разработчиков включил. Как добиться эмуляции на реальном устройстве, да еще хотелось бы по Вайфай? Читал статью `http://microsin.net/programming/android/adb-debug-application.html` - нет там драйвера, не устанавливается. Что делать?

Comment: про эмуляцию задал вопрос в отдельной теме: `http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/515657/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9`