# Как организовать отладку андроид-приложения на реальном устройстве через ВайФай

Tags: android-studio

На компе установлена Виндовс ХР. Мобильное устройство - Сони Хпериа зет3 компакт. Есть AndroidStudio, юсб-шнур подключен, отладка по юсб для разработчиков включена. Как добиться эмуляции на реальном устройстве, да еще хотелось бы по Вайфай? Читал статью http://microsin.net/programming/android/adb-debug-application.html - либо нет там драйвера, либо из-за того, что режим подключения телефона как камеры отсутствует, не устанавливается. При установки целевого устройства через юсб в студии, она пишет, когда запускаешь, что не нашла никакого устройства. Что делать? Распишите, пожалуйста, по шагам.

Answer (score 1):

Полностью проводить отладку по ВайФай можно на телефоне, подвергшемуся рутированию. Без рутирования можно лишь получить полуВайФай. Полу, потому что для его инициализации требуется подключение через ЮСБ, и живет такое отлаживание после инициализации до выключения компа, или телефона, или ВайФай точки. После требуется инициализация через ЮСБ. Для отладки по полуВайФай необходимо сделать 2 шага: 1. Подключить отладку через ЮСБ (подробно все ПРАВИЛЬНО описано в статье `https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/35602/` пункт 3). 2. Перевести подключение через ВайФай (описано в статье `http://microsin.net/programming/android/adb-debug-application.html` пункт "[Отладка через Wi-Fi]", требуются знания использования командной строки в Виндовс, для перехода к нужной папке в командной строке используется команда "cd путь_к_нужной_папке").